# Converting HTML form to Django form

Tags: django, forms

im creating a website with django and i made the site in html before moving to django and  i know need to know how to create this in a djang form and store is in a model, any help much appreciated

```
 <form>
        <div class="newEvent">
            <fieldset id="ResultSheet">
                    <legend>Result Sheet</legend>
                         Event: <br>
                    <select name="Events" id="Events">
                                <option disabled selected value> --SELECT AN 
      OPTION 
        BELOW-- </option>
                        <option value="100 Metres">100 Metres</option>
                        <option value="200 Metres">200 Metres</option>
                        <option value="300 Metres">300 Metres</option>
                        <option value="400 Metres">400 Metres</option>
                        <option value="800 Metres">800 Metres</option>
                        <option value="1500 Metres">1500 Metres</option>
                        <option value="400 Metres">400 Metres</option>
                        <option value="Hurdels">Hurdels</option>
                        <option value="Shot Put">Shot Put</option>
                        <option value="Discus">Discus</option>
                        <option value="Javelin">Javelin</option>
                        <option value="Long Jump">Long Jump</option>
                        <option value="High Jump">High Jump</option>
                        <option value="Triple Jump">Triple Jump</option>
                         <option value="4x100 Metres Relay">4x100 Metres 
    relay</option>
                </select>

                <div class="newParticipant"> 
                <br>
                    Placing: <input type="number" name="placing" min="1">
                    First name: <input type="text" name="fisrtName">
                    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName">
                    Result: <input type="number" name="result">
                </div>
            <input type="button" class="newPupil button" name="newPupil" value="New participant"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
<input type="button" id="addEvent" name="addEvent" value="Add Event" class="button" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button value="Refresh Page" onClick="refreshPage()" class="button">REFRESH</button>
```

Comment: Do you have models? You need two models(one also can do) Participant or User model and Event model, have you created that?

Comment: i have not created any models yet as unsure what models to make

Comment: can i do it with one model?

Comment: What I see in the Html you need User model(already in django) and an event model.

Comment: @TESTING It depends what are the important fields that you would like to get stored in your database. So what are the fields that you want to store in your database ?

Comment: i would like to store the placing, first name , last name and the result for each participant in each event

Comment: will the JAVASCRIPT still work with django form?

Comment: i want to store it all in one model, but have the buttons working to add a new event and a new participant within that event.

Comment: have abreak in the model to represent each event?? or something else??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments that you need to store `event`, `placing`, `first name` , `last name` and the `result`. The django form for the same would look like this:

forms.py:

**Form**:-

```
from django import forms 
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('Option 1', 'Option 1'),('Option 2', 'Option 2'),)
    events = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    placing = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    result = forms.IntegerField()
```

Or

**ModelForms**:-

```
from django import forms
from .models import model_name
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator 

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (('Option 1', 'Option 1'),('Option 2', 'Option 2'),)
    events = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    placing = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    result = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
      model = model_name
      fields = ['events', 'placing', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'result']
```

**Note:**

In case of `ModelForm` you don't need to specify those fields  (unless you want to modify them for your forms) if they already exist in your model.

For example if you already have `first_name` specified in your model and you don't wanna modify it then you can remove it from your ModelForm and just include it in `fields` under `Meta` class [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Comment: what if i wanted it to be a model form, so that i can store it?

Comment: thanks for your help, how would i then render this form within the template?

Comment: is there a way for me to share the whole project?

Comment: can u help me with the other problem of rendering it in the template and having the javascript buttons still working?

Comment: you don't need to use javascript if you are rendering the form from your django view to your template.

Comment: how do i rend it in my template?

Comment: That cannot be answered in here as its a different question you need to ask it as a separate question. But I would suggest you to do first research you will find it online. And based on that research if you get any problem then you can post that as question here on stack overflow.